# Transform category, start_time, end_time DataFrame for plotting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 32656 entries, 94418 to 2
Data columns (total 8 columns):
customer_id             32656 non-null object
session_id              32656 non-null int64
start                   32656 non-null datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
end                     32656 non-null datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
length                  32656 non-null timedelta64[ns]
category                32656 non-null object
rounded_start           32656 non-null datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
rounded_end             32656 non-null datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles]
dtypes: datetime64[ns, America/Los_Angeles](4), int64(1), object(2), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 2.2+ MB
```

I also create a DateTimeIndex:

```
rng = pd.date_range(df['rounded_start'].min(), end=df['rounded_start'].max(), freq='5Min')
```

How do I tie the two datasets together so that I can plot each point in the range on the x-axis and shows the count of how many categories are included during that time?

Comment: For future reference, it makes it much easier to answer a question if the asker provides code to replicate some sample data to work with.  As your question is presented, a person providing an answer won't be able to validate against what your expectations are.

Comment: Thanks :)  Week 1 with pandas - still learning the ropes!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will work though I haven't verified.

```
df_count = pd.DataFrame(index=rng)

def count_cats(x, df):
    date = x.name[0]
    condition1 = df.start <= date
    condition2 = df.end >= date
    df_slice = df.loc[condition1 & condition2, 'category']
    return pd.Series([df_slice.unique().size], index=['CountCats'])

df_count = df_count.apply(lambda x: count_cats(x, df))
```